# Why Hashmap is not synchronized, where internally Hashmap implements Hashtable(which is synchronized).

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

Why Hashmap is not synchronized even when Hashmap implements Hashtable internally which is synchronized.

Comment: hashmap doesn't uses hashtable in any way. hashmap is not synchronized because it was never meant to be, it's simple implementation of maintaining a bucket of hashcode and a linkedlist assigned to that hashcode with key-value pair as nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does NOT implement (or extend to be more precise) Hashtable. It implements Map, which is an interface and says nothing about synchronization policy:

```
public class HashMap<K,V>
  extends AbstractMap<K,V>
  implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```